# What should I look for in a camera system for taking still life photographs?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, mirrorless

I would like to buy a decent camera and lenses for shooting photos with fruits, vegetables and other objects of similar size. I have a [NanGuang NGT6240 Portable Light Box 60 x 60 x 60 cm](https://www.lazada.sg/nanguang-ng-t6240-portable-led-studio-lighting-case-30734690.html) and I'm currently shooting with my phone - Samsung Galaxy A5 (2007). It's so easy to shoot with a phone!

What should I look for in a camera system for taking such photos? What kind of lenses are suitable for this task?

These are probably the best shots I could manage to take until now.

I would like to take some photos outside too, but that would happen quite rarely.

The best such photos I could find until now were taken with [Nikon D300](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6d/Kiwi_%28Actinidia_chinensis%29_2_Luc_Viatour.jpg/800px-Kiwi_%28Actinidia_chinensis%29_2_Luc_Viatour.jpg) and [Nikon 700](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6b/Fagopyrum_esculentum_02_13.jpg/800px-Fagopyrum_esculentum_02_13.jpg) - amazing photos but certainly out of my budget. Which EVIL/Hybrid/MILC cameras are closest to such performance?

[image: enter link description here]
[image: enter link description here]
[image: enter link description here]

Comment: This is getting downvotes and close votes because a) we don't do "tell me what camera to buy" questions here (because the camera models change so quickly, and because those questions invariably attract people championing for their favorite brand rather than giving unbiased answers). And, "a good camera" is very subjective — what's good for you might not be for someone else. **But**, I think there is a good question in here; can you rephrase it as "What should I look for in a camera system for taking still life photographs?"

Comment: Thanks, I changed the title. I've also cut some parts of the text and I'm ready to cut more, where indicated. You can also cut anything from it wherever necessary.

Comment: You also need to remove "what do I buy?" type questions from the text, as well as remove additional questions that aren't about "what features do I look for?" and ask them as separate questions.  You may want to concentrate on camera lens specifications for macro shooting. Also, the linked images are from wikimedia. Are they your images? Or just examples of what you want to shoot? It isn't clear from the text.

Comment: @inkista - I removed more text. Those are my photos, [I have a Wikimedia Commons account](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:ListFiles/Fructibus&ilshowall=1).

Answer (score 3):

Frankly, any camera with a flash hotshoe, RAW capability, and full Manual mode would probably be a good choice, so you could take better control over the lighting than you can with a small light tent and (probably) continuous lights.  [Off-camera lighting](https://strobist.blogspot.com/2009/06/food-photography-made-easy-lunch-box.html) is liable to do more for this type of shooting than any specific camera/lens combination.

You don't need an interchangeable lens camera or a big big sensor to do this type of shooting, and in fact, a small-sensor camera is going to have an edge on macro shooting, because of the deeper DoF produced with the smaller/shorter lenses that pair with smaller sensors.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody can answer your question absolutely right.  There are lot of cameras that fit your conditions perfectly. I can shoot fruits with many Olympus cameras with various lenses (I have them all) and with Canon cameras (I have them too) and with Panasonic cameras (I can ask my wife to give me her cameras). And I think Ninon owners say the same and so on fourth...

To my mind: practically any camera with changeable lenses can approve your suggestions. So it's only you choice - go to the shop take the cameras with changeable lenses into your hands, decide what do you like. Then calculate what lense could be suitable for your task.

Comment: And bring a pear and test the camera in the shop.

Comment: Why not? :) I did bring some objects for that :)

Comment: Let's imagine I got the Mark II with the two lenses. Which of the two lenses is suited for such shots? "14 - 42 mm EZ" or "40 - 150 mm"?